# Twitter bootstrap dropdown button not working after and ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML contained in a div tag. When the button is clicked, the sibling unordered list should be populated with the elements returned from the ajax call.

Looking at the console in chrome developer tools, the list items are being populated, but the dropdown isn't triggered when I click on it.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle     collateralButton" data-toggle="dropdown">?<span class="caret"></span></button><ul  class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"></ul></div><div class="carousel owl-carousel"></div>
```

Here is the jQuery event handler with the ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', '.collateralButton', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var questionId = $('.collateralButton').parent('.btn-group').parent('.collateralWindow').siblings('.answerForm').find('.submissionForm').attr('data-questionid');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://focusneedsassessmentservice.azurewebsites.net/api/needsassessment/' + questionId +'/additionalmedialist/',
            success: function (additionalMediaList) {
                $.each(additionalMediaList, function (idx, media) {
                    $this.siblings('.dropdown-menu').append("<li class=\"collateralItem\"  data-content=\"" + media.Data + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + media.Name + "</a></li>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put it in a fiddle WITHOUT your ajax call, but still injecting the values on button click, and it works. So clearly either your ajax call is not coming back with the appropriate data, or you're not injecting into the appropriate spot...

[Simplified Fiddle that Works](http://jsfiddle.net/L43Th/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.collateralButton', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var questionId = $('.collateralButton').parent('.btn-group').parent('.collateralWindow').siblings('.answerForm').find('.submissionForm').attr('data-questionid');

        $('.dropdown-menu').append("<li class=\"collateralItem\"  data-content=\"blah blah\"><a href=\"#\">blah blah</a></li>");
        $('.dropdown-menu').append("<li class=\"collateralItem\"  data-content=\"blah blah\"><a href=\"#\">blah blah</a></li>");    
});
```

I would suggest losing your `$this.siblings('.dropdown-menu')` code for something simpler like `$('.dropdown-menu')` for now (until you get it working) and put in some debug statements around your ajax call, as when I tried your ajax call I never got a success message back, probably due to not having a valid answerID guid.